# Nginx is corrupting files on download

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

i'm having a problem with my application made with php and the Laravel Framework.

The issue is with file uploads/downloads.

When i submit files to the server it stores them good, but when i try to download an uploaded file larger than 100KB it just downloads part of it making it corrupt.

Tried a lot of options by adjusting php.ini settings, nginx settings and still can't solve it.

Here is my current configuration for nginx:

nginx.conf

```
user developer;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
     # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Now here is my nginx site config:

```
server {

    listen 8002 default_server;
    server_name localhost 172.20.74.229 cadeco.dev;

    root /var/www/current/cadeco/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/cadeco.dev-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/cadeco.dev-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    include h5bp/basic.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Then here are the related settings of php.ini from (/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini):

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60

memory_limit = 512M

upload_max_filesize = 50M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

And finally here is my php script that does the file download:

```
public function downloadFile($file)
{
    $filePath = storage_path('app/uploads/').$file;

    if (Storage::exists($file))
    {
        return response()->download($filePath);
    }

    Flash::error('File does not exists!');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance! :D

Comment: And the million dollar question - how did you determine it's corrupt?

Comment: I have opened with a text editor and compared the content with the original one, just part of the original is in the downloaded file.

Answer (score 3):

i figured it out!.

I checked the error log for this nginx site and found this error:

```
*10 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/4/00/0000000004" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 172.20.73.101, server: localhost, request: XXXXX
```

This error ocurred because some time ago we changed the user to www-data  to start services like the php-fpm, but i forgot to change it for nginx.

Changed the user to www-data and now everything works as it should!

Thanks!